# changing frames in flash as2

Tags: flash

I am creating a movie in flash!
In my first frame I have a triangle, second is a square, third is a rectagle and fourth is a circle.

I have created the 4 frames as stated! I want to set up an array so lets say (circle,triangle,circle,square,triangle,rectangle) I then want the movie to play like that with a second or two in between each frame?

```
**Error** Scene=Scene 1, layer=Layer 1, frame=1:Line 2: Statement must appear within on/onClipEvent handler
 var active = 1;
```

**Error** Scene=Scene 1, layer=Layer 1, frame=1:Line 3: Statement must appear within on/onClipEvent handler
     var timer = setInterval(gotoNext, 1000);

**Error** Scene=Scene 1, layer=Layer 1, frame=1:Line 5: Statement must appear within on/onClipEvent handler
     function gotoNext() {

Total ActionScript Errors: 4     Reported Errors: 4

Answer (score 0):

if you compile your movie (CTRL+ENTER, CMD+ENTER) it will play your movie and will show the frames in the original order. If you can tell exactly what you are trying to do, we can help a bit more :)

Rob

---

Put this code on your first frame:

```
stop();
var active = 1;
var timer = setInterval(gotoNext, 1000);

function gotoNext() {
 active = active + 1 <= _totalframes ? active + 1 : 1;
 gotoAndStop(active);
}
```

This code will go through the frames (no array needed) every second one-by-one. The `setInterval` instance will call the `gotoNext()` function every second and will increment the `active` variable's value, then moves the playhead to the next frame. If it reaches the last frame, it goes to the first frame, creating an infinite loop.

---

Ok then, modify the code as below:

```
stop();
var frames = ['rectangle', 'circle', 'triangle', 'square'];
var active = 1;
var timer = setInterval(gotoNext, 1000);

function gotoNext() {
 active = active + 1 <= _totalframes ? active + 1 : 1;
 gotoAndStop(frames[active]);
}
```

This code will use the `frames` array and will move the playhead to the active value of the array. What you need to do is to add labels on every frame with exactly the same names as in the array.

Check out this link to see how to use frame labels:
http://the-dude.co.uk/tutorials/what-are-frame-labels-and-how-do-you-use-them-flash-as2/

Good luck,
Rob

Comment: Basically im new to action script & flash so im not too familiar with it but, I have created the 4 frames as stated! I want to set up an array so lets say (circle,triangle,circle,square,triangle,rectangle) I then want the movie to play like that with a second or two in between each frame?

Comment: Please see my amended answer.

Comment: I need to use an arry.could i write it like I said above in the comment? I tried your code but its coming up as having errors :/ **Error** Scene=Scene 1, layer=Layer 1, frame=1:Line 2: Statement must appear within on/onClipEvent handler
     var active = 1;
**Error** Scene=Scene 1, layer=Layer 1, frame=1:Line 3: Statement must appear within on/onClipEvent handler
     var timer = setInterval(gotoNext, 1000);

**Error** Scene=Scene 1, layer=Layer 1, frame=1:Line 5: Statement must appear within on/onClipEvent handler
     function gotoNext() {
Total ActionScript Errors: 4 Reported Errors: 4

Comment: You put the code on a movieclip instance on the stage. You should put the code on the first frame on an empty layer on main timeline. Try it, then let's see your array thing.

Comment: Ok its Working now thanks that was so simple! Now with the array, do i write that function under the other one? Lets just say I want them to show up on the screen in the order---- circle, octagon,circle,square,triangle,circle ? How would i do that?

Comment: I added the requested tweaks to my answer. If that sorts you out, please accept it.